# How to Insert OR Update a row based on custom composite primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below

```
mysql> desc cust_vend_relation ;

+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| customer_id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_id             | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_label         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_name           | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cust_ven_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| city                  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

sample data :

```
mysql> select customer_id , vendor_id , address_label , vendor_name ,cust_ven_id ,city from cust_vend_relation;
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+
| customer_id | vendor_id  | address_label | vendor_name    | cust_ven_id | city           |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+
|         267 | 5000821693 | Office        | Imax Vendor 01 |         247 | Hyderabad      |
|         266 | 5000821693 | office        | Imax Vendor 01 |         256 | Hyderabad      |
|         266 | 5000821693 | home          | Imax Vendor 01 |         258 | Hyderabad      |
|         266 | 5000821693 | ttttt         | Imax Vendor 01 |         260 | Hyderabad      |
|         272 | 5000821693 | home          | Imax Vendor 01 |         261 | Hyderabad city |
|         270 | 5000821693 | Haii          | Imax Vendor 01 |         262 | Hyderabad city |
+-------------+------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+
```

As per the table structure , i dont have any primary key on which i can depend to say if its duplicate (The only case i can say is that **address_label**  and the **vendor_id**  columns can be repeated  )

Could you please let me know how can i use Insert Or update in this case ??

```
INSERT INTO cust_vend_relation (customer_id, vendor_id, address_label,vendor_name,city) 
VALUES (267, 5000821693, 'office' , 'Imax Vendor 01' , 'Hyderabad') ON DUPLICATE KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two columns unique constraint on (address_label , vendor_id)... 
You have cust_ven_id as primary key !

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, a candidate unique key would be the triplet of columns `customer_id, vendor_id, address_label`.  If these columns (or some other set) are indeed guaranteed to be unique, then create a unique index on them:

```
create unique index idx_ cust_vend_relation_3 on cust_vend_relation(customer_id, vendor_id, address_label);
```

You can then express the `insert` as:

```
INSERT INTO cust_vend_relation (customer_id, vendor_id, address_label, vendor_name, city) 
    VALUES (267, 5000821693, 'office' , 'Imax Vendor 01' , 'Hyderabad')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE vendor_name = VALUES(vendor_name),
              city = VALUES(city);
```